# How do I check if an object property contains all values from a specified array?

Tags: javascript

```
const gyms = [
  {
    "name": "gym1",
    "equipment": ["nothing"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym2",
    "equipment": ["barbell", "kettlebell"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym3",
    "equipment": ["barbell","dumbbell","jump rope"]
  }
]

equipmentNeeded = ["barbell","jump rope"]
```

I have an object (**gyms**) that contains all available equipment.

I also have an array (**equipmentNeeded**) that contains all the equipment I need a gym to have so I know if I should go or not.

I can get it to work if a variable is a single word string (i.e. I choose only a single piece of equipment), but I'm stuck on if I have multiple values to compare.

This is where I'm at, currently:

```
for (i=0;i < gyms.length; i++) {
  if (gyms[i]["equipment"].includes(equipmentNeeded)) {
    console.log(gyms[i]["type"] + " has all needed equipment")
  } else {
    console.log(gyms[i]["type"] + " doesn't have needed equipment")
  }
}
```

Comment: Use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) to check for all matching array elements.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it in the following way -

#### Working Code -

```js
const gyms = [
  {
    "name": "gym1",
    "equipment": ["nothing"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym2",
    "equipment": ["barbell", "kettlebell"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym3",
    "equipment": ["barbell","dumbbell","jump rope"]
  }
]

const equipmentNeeded = ["barbell","jump rope"]

const filteredGyms = gyms.filter((gym) => {  
  return equipmentNeeded.every(e => gym.equipment.includes(e));
});

console.log(filteredGyms)
```

#### Explanation

- The above code just maps through each element in gyms and for each element(I have named it `gym` used in `filter` function) it checks whether every element inside `equimentNeeded` (using [`every()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) which just checks whether all elements in the array pass the test implemented by the provided function) is present inside the `gym` (<- which current element under iteration).
- Lastly, the whole code will return you a `filteredGym` array which will just be including the gyms that fit or match your requirements.
- ```
  equipmentNeeded.every(e => gym.equipment.includes(e));
  ```

  The above statement just returns a boolean value specifying whether the current object of `gyms` array is having all the `equipmentNeeded`. If the boolean is true, the current object is included in `filteredGyms` or else it is filtered out.

---

I would suggest you to avoid using direct `for-loops` in JS unless its totally needed (there's nothing bad to it but its better to use other in-built methods provided by JS like [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce), etc which would get most of the job done).

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to this:

```
for (i=0;i < gyms.length; i++) {
    if(equipmentNeeded.every(eq => gyms[i]["equipment"].includes(eq))) {
        console.log(gyms[i]["type"] + " has all needed equipment")
    } else {
    console.log(gyms[i]["type"] + " doesn't have needed equipment")
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a function like that to check whether an array of some strings includes all the other ones:

```js
function checkEquipment(itemsOwned, itemsNeeded) {
    for(let itemNeeded of itemsNeeded) {
        if(!itemsOwned.includes(itemNeeded)) {
            return false;   
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Now you can iterate over all gyms to check if some of them suits you or not:

```js
const gyms = [{
    "name": "gym1",
    "equipment": ["nothing"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym2",
    "equipment": ["barbell", "kettlebell"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym3",
    "equipment": ["barbell", "dumbbell", "jump rope"]
  }
]

const equipmentNeeded = ["barbell", "jump rope"];

function checkEquipment(itemsOwned, itemsNeeded) {
  for (let itemNeeded of itemsNeeded) {
  if (!itemsOwned.includes(itemNeeded)) {
    return false;
  }
}
return true;
}

for (let gym of gyms) {
  if (checkEquipment(gym.equipment, equipmentNeeded)) {
    console.log(gym.name + " has all needed equipment")
  } else {
    console.log(gym.name + " doesn't have needed equipment")
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every). Here's an example:

```js
const gyms = [
  {
    "name": "gym1",
    "equipment": ["nothing"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym2",
    "equipment": ["barbell", "kettlebell"]
  },
  {
    "name": "gym3",
    "equipment": ["barbell","dumbbell","jump rope"]
  }
]

const equipmentNeeded = ["barbell","jump rope"];

gyms.forEach(gym => {
  if (equipmentNeeded.every(i => gym.equipment.includes(i))) {
    console.log(gym.name + " has all needed equipment");
  } else {
    console.log(gym.name + " doesn't have needed equipment");
  }
});
```

Comment: Good point. So used to writing jsx using map has become a habit lol